# How to add a fixed positioned summary row to the grid with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

> I have a grid with infinite scrolling.Is it possible to add a summary row to the grid with fixed position i.e bottom of the grid.
>   Whenever the grid is scrolled to the threshold the store loads with new page data,at the same time summary data should also be refreshed.
>   Any ideas or suggestions?
>
> ExtJs version : 4.1

Comment: have you try [bbar](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-bbar) ?

Comment: yes,tried bbar already.Actually it wont help as I want to display total for all the columns and columns can be added/removed.So is it possible to design a bbar in a way that it looks like a summary row or else is it possible to move summary row so that it is always visible.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16549178/2085604

You can use the dock config to fix your row:

```
features: [{
        ftype: 'summary',
        dock: 'bottom'
}],
```

I don't know if this would work with infinite scroll. You can try.

API and example here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Summary

Comment: dock:bottom is supported by ExtJs4.2 and I am using ExtJs4.1

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, didn't check the version.